# How can I ensure a given part of my lowpoly retopo sticks to the correct part of the highpoly sculpt

Tags: modeling, modifiers, sculpting, retopology

My character sculpt has a crease on the upper eyelid that has proven to be quite difficult to deal with, as my retopo is quite lowpoly and subdividing it causes the retopo crease to no longer align with the crease in the highpoly sculpt of the character. This deviation is so extreme that it prevents a shrinkwrap modifier from moving the vertices back to the correct place, generating a glitched mesh instead.

[image: wireframe view of the issue happening]

It may be a bit hard to see in the above screenshot but if you pay close attention you'll notice the upper eyelid of the retopo (yellow wireframe) does not match the highpoly sculpt (solid grey matcap). Here's a simplified .blend file of the same scene:

[image]

I've only been able to fix this issue by applying the subdivision surface modifier and then moving vertices manually to the right place, then using a shrinkwrap modifier on top of that, but I don't think the above solution is ideal as it involves destructively applying modifiers, so iterating further on the original sculpt is not possible without redoing all the work moving vertices after applying the subsurf.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: is the retopo for animation (can the eye blink?) or is it just for texturing?

Comment: @Blunder this project is just to figure out the general workflow for character creation. It will not be animated but the work I'm doing here will be responsible for defining the workflow I'll use for creating characters that could be animated.